# Husky/lint-staged is it possible to exclude/ignore file?

Tags: husky, git-husky, lint-staged

Is it possible to exclude/ignore a file when using Husky/lint-staged hooks?

Looking through the docs atm but not having any luck finding anything on this.

Was hoping there was something like an

```
/*ignore*/
```

tag that I could add.

To make lint-staged ignore certain files that were causing formatting issues.

Any thought on this greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ended up adding

```
.prettierignore
```

file.

Not ideal but seems to do the job ok.

Comment: I believe thats actually the ideal solution. Lint-staged removed the configuration to ignore files and their docs mention using .prettierignore as the solution.
Source:https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged#configuration

Comment: I do not use the `prettier` package, thus adding such file is not ideal.

Comment: In my case it was .eslintignore file

Answer (score 21):

I finally found out how to do this (at least as of `lint-staged v11.1.2`)

In `package.json`:

```json
"lint-staged": {
  "!(path/to/excluded/dir/**/*)*.ts": [
    "eslint --fix",
    "prettier --write"
  ]
}
```

Note the globstar pattern is within the negation pattern and not outside it. This ensures that subdirectories are also excluded.

Comment: Excellent for me!!  "!(.yarn/**)*.[jt]s?(x)"

Answer (score 11):

While configuring lint-staged in package.json or If you're using any other IDE, in order to ignore/exclude files by lint-Staged and husky hooks, you can add an "ignore" key in the lint-staged object to make it ignore whatever packages or files you want to ignore. Use the following extensible syntax:

```
{
  "lint-staged": {
    "linters": {
      "src/**/*.js": ["formatter --write", "git add"],
    },
    "ignore": ["node_modules", "dist", "package-lock.json"]  }
}
```

Just add the target pattern to 'linters' object and all the ignored files which you might be adding previously to .prettierignore to "ignore" key of lint-Staged object. And there you go!

Comment: This config format does not work with lint-staged 9.5 (I'm not sure which version it changed.)

Comment: I think `ignore` is not supported anymore. You can use `"!(*test).js"` https://stackoverflow.com/a/60062972/569751

Comment: Life saver ! thx ! works perfectly well with lint-staged ^8.x.x

Comment: this has been deprecated. the only way i got mine to work was `git rm -f <file>` and add `<file>` to `.gitignore`

Answer (score 7):

If anyone still looking, take a look at this https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged#filtering-files It has good examples.

#### Filtering files

Linter commands work on a subset of all staged files, defined by a *glob pattern*. `lint-staged´ uses [micromatch](https://github.com/micromatch/micromatch) for matching files with the following rules:

- If the glob pattern contains no slashes (`/`), micromatch's `matchBase` option will enabled, so globs match a file's basename regardless of directory:

  - **`"*.js"`** will match all JS files, like `/test.js` and `/foo/bar/test.js`
  - **`"!(*test).js"`**. will match all JS files, except those ending in `test.js`, so `foo.js` but not `foo.test.js`
- If the glob pattern does contain a slash (`/`), it will match for paths as well:

  - **`"./*.js"`** will match all JS files in the git repo root, so `/test.js` but not `/foo/bar/test.js`
  - **`"foo/**/\*.js"`** will match all JS files inside the`/foo`directory, so`/foo/bar/test.js`but not`/test.js`

Comment: I played/fighted a little bit with it. I use : "lint-staged": { "projects/**!(*node_nodules)!(*dist)/*(package-lock).{js,ts,json,css,scss,html}": ["prettier --write"]}. Micromatch supports a nice array syntax, but it cannot be used with lint-staged.

Comment: Did you tried this https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged#example-use-your-own-globs ?

Comment: no, I wanted to have it all in package.json. I ended up getting the result I need (modifying further the above code). I find the result not so nice to read, it feels a bit like regexes. I perceive the old syntax as more explit and more accessible to someone reading a package.json for the first time.

Comment: my final syntax (for the lazy ppl who prefer to copy and modify stuff) : "projects/!(node_modules|dist)/**/*.{js,ts,json,css,scss,html}"

Answer (score 5):

So I've been trying to find an answer for this for an entire day and looking at all the forums suggested that they use minimatch for glob check which might have been correct for older versions but they use micromatch for new version and to solve this issue we can use their pattern to exclude certain directories
So in your .lintstagedrc you can add the following pattern to avoid certain folders

```
{
  "*.{json,md,html,scss}": ["prettier --write", "git add"],
  ["**/!(folder1|folder2)/*.ts"]: ["tslint --project tsconfig.json -c tslint.commit.json --fix", "prettier --write", "git add"]
}
```

So the glob here is an actual array and make sure not to pass this array within a string else it won't recognize the patterns also **do not include** **/*.ts the reason being lint-staged automatically converts this into a matchBase comparision if it finds / in the pattern so including this will also match against your folder1|folder2 files.

Answer (score 0):

To address this, I've published a tool called `@skarab/eslint-staged`.

This CLI tool enhances `lint-staged` by ensuring it respects the ignored files, avoiding the common issue where ignored files still get processed.

It's straightforward to use, first install:

```bash
pnpm add @skarab/eslint-staged --save-dev
```

And add the following to your `lint-staged` config:

```json
{
  "*": [
    "pnpm eslint-staged --fix --max-warnings=0",
    "pnpm prettier --write --ignore-unknown"
  ]
}
```

I believe this could be a helpful solution for those experiencing similar issues. The package is open for contributions, and I'd love to hear your feedback!

You can find it here: https://github.com/skarab42/eslint-staged

Happy coding!